# Javascript, event handler cannot be named click

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

Today I was implementing a click listerener and stumbled on the following:

```js
function click (val) {
  console.log(val)
} 

function random (val) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

```css
div:hover {
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="click(1)">test1</div>
<div onclick="random(1)">test2</div>
```

The method for handling events cannot be named 'click'. Click is not a reserved keyword like `for`, `if` or `while` so why can't I use it? Are there any other function names which I cannot use?

Comment: Why? What is the issue with your code?

Comment: The onclick of the first div doesn't work

Comment: Regarding "marked as duplicate". I don't see any mention of "click" as reserved name anywhere

Comment: Yes I want to reopen it also

Comment: Would like to know why my function inamed click isn't working

Comment: This question have nothing to do about the one marked as duplicate...

Comment: it's not about javascript, because if you add the click listener in the JS instead of an HTML inline `onclick=...` it will work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click method is getting called.

Comment: Oww, It call the click method with the onclick, I get it now thanks!

Comment: @zakaria-acharki This duplicate does not apply. The problem is not caused by a reserved keyword conflict. The problem is caused by the function on the `this` context overriding a function on the global object. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20608263).

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen Saw your deleted question after it was deleted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909146/single-page-application-spa-when-to-use-server-side-rendering . Don't be frustrated, this just isn't SO kind of question. Try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . In short, your assumptions are correct. Google supports JS and SPAs as good as static websites, at least in theory. SEO may be == Google in some markets and != in other markets.

Comment: @estus thanks for the explaination! I deleted it because it got like 3 instant downvotes but I guess it was the wrong question to ask

Comment: You're welcome. The question seems to be worded reasonably well to me, just wrong place to ask. Such questions are usually closed with neutral votes, I agree that downvoting without any explanation isn't very constructive in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` attribute code is evaluated within the context of DOM element it belongs to. Since an element [has `click` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), it shadows `click` global.

An [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkiRQNW5HcR8ha7mItdJ?p=preview):

```
<div onclick="
  console.log(
    typeof click === 'function', // true
    this.click === click, // true
    document.querySelector('div').click === click // true
  );
">test</div>
```

Situations like this one confirm that modern practice to avoid globals where possible and use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` is justified.

Comment: Kind of already figured it out, but still thanks for your answer!